# Scrape data from a paginated website which was blocking the request when i use beautifulsoup, selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrape data from this site "https://www.findhelp.org/care/support-network--san-francisco-ca?postal=94105" . I Tried using selenium, beautifulsoup but cant able to scrape the data because the site was blocking scrapers. I want to find a way to scrape the data in this site.

Any solution for this problem will be highly appreciated.

I tried these two approaches:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="https://www.findhelp.org/care/support-network--san-francisco-ca?postal=94105"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246'}
reqs = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Second one:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
#object of Options class
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#add user Agent
op.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246")
#set chromedriver.exe path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Vinay Edula\Desktop\evva\findhelp\chromedriver.exe",options=op)
#maximize browser
driver.maximize_window()
#launch URL
driver.get("https://www.findhelp.org/search_results/94105")
time.sleep(15)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get into the site by passing this user agent in the header.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246
```

Comment: I tried using this in header, i got response in code as ">Sorry, something about your browser or browsing activity made us think you were a robot.To regain access, please make sure both cookies and JavaScript are enabled in your web browser, then reload the page. Our site needs them to function!"

Comment: Can you include the code you have tried please.

Comment: I have edited the question with the code snippets.

Comment: try adding this as a cookie: `{'ab_session':'FvKfJMO4mlmnJFmC8twnv0XmnXS9to9I+0oTDykxs9Y=QC4UTEGZBRUUBF2080XQ0W6EK0GTHWGY0K90G2SJ4YR44IRON9;',}`

Comment: still same error